# Is this line from Zelda 2 the only time Link's thoughts are verbalized?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

In Zelda 2, there's a mirror that you have to find in a random house. When you crouch down and pick it up, one of the game's text crawls reads as follows:

[image]

As far as I can tell, this is the first and only time that Link's thoughts are verbalized directly to the player. As most everyone knows, Link is a silent hero who only grunts and yells. Obviously moreso in the later games. The games even make fun of that occasionally by having characters ask him why he's so quiet or whatever.

Are there any other instances in the series where Link speaks his mind, be it through a voice actor or written dialog box? CD-i does not count :)

Comment: Don't forget his classic line: '...'

Comment: Link has two "lines" in The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker: "Come on!" and "Meeew!". Not sure if that counts as dialog.

Comment: Why does CD-i not count? Repressed memories? ;-)

Comment: Excuse me, princess!

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo When does he say "Meeew!"?

Comment: @Cyberson When sneaking up on that one girl on Windfall island at night after your second visit to the Forbidden Fortress to unlock one of the bottles.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Oh yeah, but would you really consider that talking? I think it's more on the same level as the shouting he does when he's fighting.

Comment: @Cyberson Yea, admittedly it's not much, but it is something other than a grunt or a shout.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Link has no written or spoken dialogue of note in any game, with the exception of two instances in *Zelda II: The Adventure of Link*. ([Source](http://zeldawiki.org/Link#Characteristics)) This doesn't mean that Link is a mute, per se (he can interact in conversations, after all), rather, Link's lack of dialogue is simply a design choice from Nintendo.

Comment: Where at on the page is the part that relates specifically to this question?

Comment: @Cyberson I linked the section: "Link does not speak or have any written dialog (other than in two instances in The Adventure of Link, and in The Wind Waker within the Tower of the Gods where Link calls "Come on!" to the Servants of the Tower)"

Comment: I completely forgot about that Wind Waker one. I feel terrible considering that's my favorite Zelda game!

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj Don't feel too bad, I just finished the game like a couple weeks ago and I had also forgotten about that.

Comment: Note: this answer discounts the CDi Zelda games, which are not Nintendo games, but a product of Phillips gaining the license to the characters.